# How the epoll(), mutex and semaphore alike system calls are implemented behind the scene?

Tags: linux, multithreading, asynchronous, linux-kernel, operating-system

This is really a question confusing me for a long time. I tried googling a lot but still don't quite understand. My question is like this:

for system calls such as epoll(), mutex and semaphore, they have one thing in common: as soon as something happens(taking mutex for example, a thread release the lock), then a thread get woken up(the thread who are waiting for the lock can be woken up).

I'm wondering how is this mechanism(an event in one thread happens, then another thread is notified about this) implemented on earth behind the scene? I can only come up with 2 ways:

1. Hardware level interrupt: For example, as soon as another thread releases the lock, an edge trigger will happen.
2. Busy waiting: busy waiting in very low level. for example, as soon as another thread releases the lock, it will change a bit from 0 to 1 so that threads who are waiting for the lock can check this bit.

I'm not sure which of my guess, if any, is correct. I guess reading linux source code can help here. But it's sort of hard to a noob like me. It will be great to have a general idea here plus some pseudo code.

Comment: Who puts a thread to sleep? The kernel. Who wakes up the thread? The kernel. A simplified explanation: when thread A unlocks a mutex a syscall is invoked that enters the kernel. The kernel will then find a thread B that is blocked on that mutex and schedule it for wakeup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux kernel has a built-in object class called "wait queue" (other OSes have similar mechanisms). Wait queues are created for all types of "waitable" resources, so there are quite a few of them around the kernel. When thread detects that it must wait for a resource, it joins the relevant wait queue. The process goes roughly as following:

1. Thread adds its control structure to the linked list associated with the desired wait queue.
2. Thread calls scheduler, which marks the calling thread as sleeping, removes it from "ready to run" list and stashes its context away from the CPU. The scheduler is then free to select any other thread context to load onto the CPU instead.

When the resource becomes available, another thread (be it a user/kernel thread or a task scheduled by an interrupt handler - those usually piggy back on special "work queue" threads) invokes a "wake up" call on the relevant wait queue. "Wake up" means, that scheduler shall remove one or more thread control structures from the wait queue linked list and add all those threads to the "ready to run" list, which will enable them to be scheduled in due course.

A bit more technical overview is here:
http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2